# What GCM Sender Id android code edit text?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I know how Sender ID app option to paste formatted text to any sender id cooperate ? Now it is firmly set , but not the way I want to . I tried but it did not come together not at all , the app will fail stop .

now: *MainActivity : public  static String SENDER_ID = "123456789***"; 
I want a coded form Funkcio.java 
Funkcio:*

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(getActivity());
         GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(getActivity());
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.funkcio, container, false);
     toggle = (ToggleButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
```

// I would like to form into which the edit text sender id stamped cooperate in any app .

```
    Button regbtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button delbtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);       
wifiManager = (WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
PowerManager = (PowerManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
regbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View view) {        
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), MainActivity.SENDER_ID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
        GCMRegistrar.register(getActivity(), MainActivity.SENDER_ID);
    }       
    }); 

delbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
    public void onClick(View view) {                
        GCMRegistrar.unregister(getActivity());     
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }       
    });
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Sorry but your question isn't very clear, one thing though. If this is a new project you shouldn't use GCMREgister. Please use the new apis https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

Comment: I would like an input field into which several other projects I write sender id .

Comment: To confirm.. DO you want an app UI which has edit text where you can input sender ID? Where do you want to send this Sender_ID, please clarify.

Comment: Hy, I want a piece of code between the two.  "// I would like ... "